# Arduino power supply issue

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply, atmega

I've been playing with the ATmega328 and xbee a lot and wanted to take it to the next step and make it fully mobile. So i have decided to use 2xAA batteries along with a 5V step up to get a stable 5V output ([link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/delayed-power-supply-startup)) for the ATmega328, and a 3.3V step down to power the xbee.

The 5V step up is a [LT1300](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/lt1300.pdf) and the 3.3V step down is a [MCP1700](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21826b.pdf) (). The ATmega328 is using the [Arduino bootloader and code](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone).

My problem is that the ATmega328 is not responding when using the LT1300 even though the output is a nice and clean 5V. It is working thought if I replace the LT1300 schematic with a regular 5V DC power source.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Ok i have found the solution... a simple 1uF decoupler on pin 7 & 20 fixed the problem. I didn't think this would be necessary as the step up already has decoupling.

Comment: Doesn't the xBee module work at 3V? In that case you could directly use the battery voltage...

Comment: @clabacchio I don't think using the battery voltage directly is a good thing

Comment: @matejj could you post an oscilloscope screenshot of the 5V rail without the decoupling capacitor? I am really curious how the signal looks!

Comment: @abdullahkahraman I don't mean using it to power the ATmega, just the xBee module: it seems a waste to use a step-up and then a step-down...

Comment: You got to step-up both. 2xAA are 3V and it's not going to stay constant, right?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a scope... i'm using a multimeter. @clabacchio the battery voltage is not constant and drops rapidly. Using this particular step-up allows for stable voltage even with only 1.8V output from the batteries.

Comment: But for instance I'm using a wireless module that works with any voltage from 2V to 3.6 without problem...that's why I was asking

Comment: @clabacchio what module are you using? is it an xbee?

Comment: @matejj no 802.15.4

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have found the solution... a simple 1uF decoupler on pin 7 & 20 fixed the problem. I didn't think this would be necessary as the step up already has decoupling.